# How to use javascript to control the display or hiding of elements according to the change of the URL without refactoring the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I would like to ask. I am currently encountering a requirement. I hope that the button will appear only when a certain parameter appears in the URL. If there is no such parameter, the button will be hidden. I have already written a program, but this method requires the entire web page to be refreshed to be effective. How to make elements appear or hide as long as the URL has specific parameters without reorganizing the page? For example: The original URL is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), so the button does not appear, but the URL becomes [www.example.com/?keyword="123"](http://www.example.com/?keyword=%22123%22) and the button appears when the keyword appears. I don’t know if this can be done in practice? Or is it impossible to meet this requirement at all? Hope to get your help, I will be very grateful for your answer, thank you.

```js
// For example, the current URL is wwww.example.com.tw
const params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;

$(function(){
  if(params.get("editors")){
     $('.show').css('display','block')
  }else{
    $('.show').css('display','none')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="show">button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in two steps:

1. function `getUrlParams()` returns the URL parameters from `document.location.search`

- in this code snippet here it is simulated with a `document1` object
- e.g. replace `document1.location.search` with `document.location.search` in your own code

2. hide the button based on a URL parameter

```js
const document1 = {
  location: {
    href:     'https://example.com/some/path/page.html?foo=hi+there&editor=1',
    origin:   'https://example.com',
    pathname: '/path/page.html',
    search:   '?foo=hi+there&editor=1',
  }
}

function getUrlParams() {
  const search = document1.location.search; // replace with document.location.search
  return search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&').reduce((acc, param) => {
    let parts = param.match(/^([^=]+)=(.*)$/) || [param, param, ''];
    acc[parts[1]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[2].replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const params = getUrlParams();
console.log('params:', params);

$('document').ready(function() {
  if(params.editor) {
    $('#edit').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Edit button below is hidden because of the <tt>editor=1</tt> URL parameter:</p>
<button id="edit">Edit</button>
```

Output:

```
params: {
  "foo": "hi there",
  "editor": "1"
}
```